# RxJava - Consuming a GroupedObservable

Tags: android, rx-java

Given the following code:

```
bcxClient
  .fetchToDos()
  .flatMap(new Func1<List<BcxToDo>, Observable<BcxToDo>>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<BcxToDo> call(List<BcxToDo> bcxToDos) {
      return Observable.from(bcxToDos);
    }
  })
  .groupBy(new Func1<BcxToDo, BcxToDoList>() {
    @Override
    public BcxToDoList call(BcxToDo bcxToDo) {
      return bcxToDo.toDoList;
    }
  })
  .toList();
```

Which returns a `List<GroupedObservable<>>`. In my code, I need to count how many objects there are in each GroupedObservable. If I use the `count()` function it returns an `Observable<int>`. The following code won't work:

```
@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    int count;

    mToDoList.get(groupPosition)
        .count()
        .subscribe( new Action1<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Integer integer) {
                count = integer;
            }
        });

    return count;
}
```

If I make the local variable final, then I can't assign a value to it.

So as far as I can tell, I have two options. Store the count for each grouping in a field that belongs to the class, or transform the GroupedObservable into an alternate structure in the chain (above). If this is the case, what's the best way to do this?

This is the code I wrote to translate the GroupedObservable:

```
.flatMap( new Func1<GroupedObservable<BcxToDoList, BcxToDo>, Observable<BcxToDoList>>() {
  @Override
  public Observable<BcxToDoList> call(final GroupedObservable<BcxToDoList, BcxToDo> bcxToDoListBcxToDoGroupedObservable) {
    return bcxToDoListBcxToDoGroupedObservable
      .toList()
      .flatMap( new Func1<List<BcxToDo>, Observable<BcxToDoList>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<BcxToDoList> call(List<BcxToDo> bcxToDos) {
          bcxToDoListBcxToDoGroupedObservable.getKey().toDos.addAll( bcxToDos );

          return Observable.just( bcxToDoListBcxToDoGroupedObservable.getKey() );
        }
      });
  }
})
```

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your first attemp doesn't work, as count is a primitive value and not an object.

To get the `count`, you can block and get the value. (But the current thread will block)

```
@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    int count = mToDoList.get(groupPosition).toBlocking().single();
    return count;
}
```

If you don't want to block, using a `Pair` alike structure seems a good idea

```
 bcxClient
   .fetchToDos()
   .flatMap(Observable::from)
   .groupBy(bcxToDo-> bcxToDo.toDoList)
   .flatMap(todo -> todo.count().map(c -> new Pair(todo, c))
   .toList()
   .subscribe(pair -> //** iter over your list **//);
```

Comment: Thanks, toBlocking was the information that I was missing. If I were to go with plan B and turn the GroupedObservable into a List<BcxToDoList>, will the code I wrote work? Or will that block?

Comment: If you don't call toBlocking, you won't block.